# View error on AllItems.aspx

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list-view-threshold

This error just cropped up and has me puzzled. `This view cannot be displayed because it exceeds the list view threshold (10000 items) enforced by the administrator.` ...but what has me scratching my head is that it's on the AllItems view that was working ten minutes ago. I verified it's still set to a 100 item limit, and even created a new view based on it to be sure it wasn't corrupted somehow. Same error on both views. I reduced the new view to 1 item and still receive this error!

Comment: how many items in list, how many items you want to display on all items view? also try to close the browser or even reset the pc and then try it.

Comment: List has a few thousand items, the view is completely default, only displays 100. I'll try the resets and get back to you.

Comment: few thousands mean less than 10,000?

Comment: Correct, more like 3-4

Comment: how many columns in it specially lookup?

Comment: 10 columns are calculated, but none are lookups

Comment: two things you can try, if problem still their after reset....reduce the number of column in view or increase the list view threshold limit temp to 15000

Comment: Create a new view to query less, or more spacific items. In SP 2013, you can store 30 million records in a list. The threshold is based off of the amount of items returned in the view. You can also set you item threshold limit in Central Admin.Here is a link to the limits of SharePoint http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary

Comment: @lazoDev As stated in the question, I created a view that's only returning one item and it's still serving up the error.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE The resets did not help. However, I reduced the columns in the view down to 3 and now it works. I don't understand why though! Nothing in the view changed, and the list itself didn't change except to have some items edited, no new columns were added. I'm even more confused now!

Comment: what are you list view threshold values, could you please share?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Confirmed the LVT is set to 10k/20k admin

Comment: do one more thing, add column one at a time and test it until it fails...then check the LVT for lookupcolumn

Comment: I just added them all back in and it's still working fine! -.- The LVT for lookup columns is 8, but there aren't even any lookup columns in the list (unless a calculated column counts, but I don't think it does).

Comment: I guess I need to completely rebuild the view?

Comment: Once the threshold is reached and your view contains non-indexed columns or queries, it would fail. If you create new view with total item limit set, and add indexed columns it should work.

Comment: i dont think, if you added everything back and it is working then you all set, sometime view upset but refreshing it fix it. in you case you reduce the number of columns and it render. after that it getting the correct value.